# how to create an ordered set with a custom equals protocol in Swift?

Tags: generics, swift3

I would like to create a generic OrderedSet in Swift that maintains insertion order and uses an isEqual method defined in a companion protocol to determine if an object is already in the set. The purpose of the isEqual protocol is so I can test for equality of objects of different types, but that share a common protocol. It seems like this design should be possible, but I'm hitting a brick wall. Here is what I have so far for the generic ordered set...

```
protocol DynamicEquality {
    func isEqual(_ otherObj: DynamicEquality) -> Bool
}

struct OrderedSet<T: DynamicEquality> {
    private(set) var objects: [T] = []

    func contains(_ obj: T) -> Bool {
        for anObject in objects {
            if obj.isEqual(anObject) {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    mutating func add(_ obj: T) -> Bool {
        if !self.contains(obj) {
            objects.append(obj)
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    ....
}
```

Then, the OrderedSet would be used in the following way...

```
protocol BaseProtocol: DynamicEquality {
    var baseText: String { get }
    var baseNum: Int  { get }
}

extension BaseProtocol {
    func isEqual(_ otherObj: DynamicEquality) -> Bool {
        if let otherBase  = otherObj as? BaseProtocol {
            return self.baseText == otherBase.baseText &&
                self.baseNum == otherBase.baseNum
        }

        return false
    }
}

class ClassA: BaseProtocol {
    var baseText = ""
    var baseNum = 0
}

class ClassB: BaseProtocol {
    var baseText = ""
    var baseNum = 0
}

var orderedSet = OrderedSet<BaseProtocol>()
let objA = ClassA()
orderedSet.add(objA)
let objB = ClassB()
orderedSet.add(objB)
```

The result of this code should be that objA is added to the set but not objB since they are equal according to isEqual(), but instead I get this error:

> error: using 'BaseProtocol' as a concrete type conforming to
>   protocol 'DynamicEquality' is not supported
>   var orderedSet = OrderedSet< BaseProtocol>()
>                               ^

Does anyone have another way to accomplish what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a class conforming to `BaseProtocol`, make your custom classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` inherit from `BaseClass` and create an `OrderedSet` with `BaseClass` elements.

```
class BaseClass: BaseProtocol {
    var baseText: String {
        get {
            return ""
        }
    }
    var baseNum: Int {
        return 0
    }
}

class ClassA: BaseClass {
}

class ClassB: BaseClass {
}

var orderedSet = OrderedSet<BaseClass>()
let objA = ClassA()
orderedSet.add(objA)
let objB = ClassB()
orderedSet.add(objB)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is certainly a possibility, but I'm trying to use a protocol instead of a base class because 1) I extend String to conform to the BaseProtocol and 2) That design precludes my concrete classes from inheriting from some other class since swift doesn't have duel inheritance.